# xcode: recommended image size for launch xib?

Tags: xcode, image, size, scale, xib

I want to scale an image to full screen size on my launch xib. What is a good size for the base image in my image set? Will 1024x1024 be enough? I'm afraid it will look too blurry on an iPad or iPad Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start with the largest target devices resolution and since the iPad Pro is 2732x2048@2x, 1024x1024 is most certainly going to look blurry on that device.

[Checkout this link for device resolutions](http://iosres.com)